# How can I replace the Q3ListView/Q3ListViewItem utilities?

Tags: qt4, qlistview, qt3

I'm updating some old code that is unfortunately heavily dependent on Q3ListView and Q3ListViewItem, its now-obsolete little helper class.

I'm assuming I can now just populate a QListView without the item layer, but in looking through the documentation, I still don't have a very good grip on that. One tutorial I found fills a QStandardItemModel with QStandardItems and then sets that as the model to the QListView, but I also came across a QAbstractListModel class that looks like it might be interesting. A couple of questions have come up:

-Is a QListView basically populated by setting some "model" to it, which itself is populated with items?

-In the old version I have, the Q3ListViewItem is subclassed like this:

```
class OurListItem : public Q3ListViewItem {
   public: 
      OurListItem(Q3ListView* parent) :Q3ListViewItem(parent) {ourData = NULL;}
      OurListItem(Q3ListViewItem* parent) :Q3ListViewItem(parent) {ourData = NULL;}
      Data* ourData; 
};
```

Considering the options available now, what is the best way to re-implement this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how clean you want the conversion to be, and how quickly you want to do the conversion, you may also want to look at [QListWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) and [QListWidgetItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html).  They are the approximate analogues in Qt4, and I think the conversion to them was usually straightforward.  As I recall (it's been quite a while), the Qt3 versions of those classes may also have had table or tree abilities (rather than just a simple list), so you may also be interested in [QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html) and [QTreeWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html) (and their associated item classes).